# Change HTML for Spanish Site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using Divi and I can't seem to update the email that shows up in the topbar in the header on the Spanish version of the site. My JS is a little rusty.

The URL is domainofclient.com/es/inicio

The element is `<span id="et-info-email">sales@domainofclient.com</span>` which needs to change to `<span id="et-info-email">ventas@domainofclient.com</span>`

What I've tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.URL.indexOf("/es/inicio/") >= 0){ 
    document.getElementById('et-info-email').innerHTML = 'ventas@domainofclient.com'    
}   
</script>
```

I've also tried the following JQ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href === "https://domainofclient.com/es/inicio/") {
        jQuery('#et-info-email').text('ventas@domainofclient.com'); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try a plugin translator that translate the strings? My favorite is WPML but if you want a free one use polylang.

Comment: please add  complete code

Comment: I'm using Polylang right now, but that particular string isn't showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. I would although try to first of all wrap the code into a function and run it only when the page is ready.

```js
function replaceEmail() {
  if(document.location.pathname.indexOf("/es/inicio") !== -1){
    document.getElementById("et-info-email").innerHTML = "ventas@domainofclient.com"
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Author">
    <title>#[[$Title$]]#</title>
</head>

<body onload="replaceEmail()">
    <span id="et-info-email">sales@domainofclient.com</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href === "https://domainofclient.com/es/inicio/") {
        jQuery('#et-info-email').text('ventas@domainofclient.com'); 
    }
});

</script>
```